# ElasticSearch with Express framework

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

I want to built a application and a api which will mainly retrieve a resource, Now I have heard a lot about `Nodejs` and `ElasticSearch` and I know little bit Nodejs and Express framework. But I don't know how will I integrated ElasticSearch with Express framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- 1st download ElasticSearch
- Inside your project / Express framework directory download ElasticSearch express driver using  `npm install elasticsearch --save`
- Run ElasticSearch Instance, By default it runs on the port 9200
- To use that module, simply create a client instance

  ```
  var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
  var client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200'
  });

  client.search({
    index: 'books',
    type: 'book',
    body: {
      query: {
        multi_match: {
          query: 'express js',
          fields: ['title', 'description']
        }
      }
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
    var hits = response.hits.hits;
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.trace(error.message);
  });
  ```
- Helpfull Link https://blog.raananweber.com/2015/11/24/simple-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-and-node-js/

Comment: i have tried this but its showing DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 2):

First, of course you need a Elasticsearch instance running.

Then, you should use official client library for Node.js: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js

To use that module, simply create a client instance

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: '<your_instance_ip>:9200',
  log: 'trace'
});
```

And then push some data to it via `client.send` and search for it using `client.search` functions.

Comment: Can you provide me some example, little bit more specific as I m new in  elasticsearch

Answer (score 2):

If You are using OSx

1.First Phase installation and running of elasticsearch

IN TERMINAL

- brew install elasticsearch //For installation
- elasticsearch //For Running

2.In Your Application Folder

2.1 For installing ES Driver

- npm install elasticsearch --save

2.2 Lets Create a router for elasticSearch

- Create FOLDER & File: routers/elastic-search-router.js

  ```
  var express= require('express');
  var router= express.Router();
  var elasticsearch=require('elasticsearch');
  var client = new elasticsearch.Client( {  
               hosts: [
                       'http://localhost:9200/',//DEFAULT URL
                      //'https://[username]:[password]@[server]:[port]/'
                      ]
   });

   /* This operation health of es */
   router.get('/health',function(req,res){
     client.cluster.health({},function(err,resp,status) {  
        if(err)
        {  console.log("-- Client Health ERROR--",err);
        }else{
           console.log("-- Client Health --",resp);
           res.send({resp});
        }
     });
   });
   /* This operation For Creating new Index of es */
   router.get('/createIndex',function(req,res){
     client.indices.create({  
          index: 'imageMap'
     },function(err,resp,status) {
     if(err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
     else {
        console.log("create",resp);
        res.send({resp});
     }
   });
  });
  module.exports =router;
  ```

2.2 Now inside Express index.js file

```
    // Setup an Express app
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var path= require('path');
    //use routers
    app.use(require(path.join(__dirname,'routers/elastic-search-router')));
    ....
```

2.3 Run the Express Server :

```
IN TERMINAL : node index.js
```

3. In your Application URL you can access each function in ur router as:

   http://localhost:3000/createIndex

   http://localhost:3000/health